# Unable to share internet by using HOSTEDNETWORK after installing AVAST recently

Tags: networking, windows-8, wifi

I was able to share my laptop's internet with my smartphone by using    this command "netsh wlan start hosted network".  But when I installed    Avast in my Windows 8 OS, I am able to start the hosted-network as    before and my smartphone also finds the virtual AP but still I can't    use internet on the smartphone. It's like the internet sharing has    been disabled by the Antivirus. How do I tell Avast that its okay to use the hosted-network?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this problem. Open Avast UI, go to settings, open Active Protections, then click firewall settings. There you will find a checkbox for internet sharing mode. Make sure it is checked. 
That's it. The hostednetwork starts working again. No need to stop the avast firewall at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem caused by Avast's firewall, it prevent TCP port traffic, so you should turn off it to solve your trouble.
Good luck